# "Parsing error: The type cast expression is expected to be wrapped with parenthesis" with React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have many inputs which the values matches properties of an object :

**Example** :

```
const [fields, setFields] = useState({
  city: ""
})
<input type="text" name="city" value={fields.city} onChange={e => handleChange(e) />
```

Now, I want to do a handleChange function which updates the object values, when the input value changes,

```
function handleChange(e) {
  setFields(...fields, [e.target.name]: e.target.value)
}
```

but when I do this, I got the error

> "Parsing error: The type cast expression is expected to be wrapped
>   with parenthesis"

,

Can someone help me ? Thank you !

Comment: `<input type="text" name="city" value={fields.city} onChange={e => handleChange(e) />`, it is missing closing curly brace `}`.

Comment: @randomSoul yes sorry it's a typo when I created the topic, but in my code it's well written

Comment: It means that you're not using JavaScript, but some other language that knows about "type cast expressions". Maybe TS or Flow? Please tag your question with it.

Comment: Well, `setFields(...fields, [e.target.name]: e.target.value)` is clearly an invalid function call. Did you mean to pass an object literal after the spreading the `fields` variable, `setFields(...fields, {[e.target.name]: e.target.value})`? If not, I have no idea what you could have meant to do here.

Comment: @Bergi i'm using javascript, i think there's an error somewhere in the line you mentioned

Comment: It seems like you are passing object to function `setFields` and objects needs to be enclosed in `{}`. Try `setFields({...fields, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})`.

Comment: @randomSoul thank you, that's it !!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing brackets around the fields, since it's an object:

```
function handleChange(e) {
  setFields({...fields, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
}
```

Also in this case it's better to use the functional form of `setState`, since the value of next state depends on the previous state:

```
function handleChange(e) {
  setFields(currentFields => ({...currentFields, [e.target.name]: e.target.value}))
}
```